# PSQL : ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8"

Tags: java, postgresql

I am trying to create a logical replication slot via the java PostgreSQL 42.0.0.jre7 API and this is my code :

```
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sampledb?characterEncoding=utf8";
Properties props = new Properties();
PGProperty.USER.set(props, "postgres");
PGProperty.PASSWORD.set(props, "root");
PGProperty.ASSUME_MIN_SERVER_VERSION.set(props, "9.6");
PGProperty.REPLICATION.set(props, "true");
PGProperty.PREFER_QUERY_MODE.set(props, "simple");
DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.postgresql.Driver());
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
PGConnection replConnection = con.unwrap(PGConnection.class);

replConnection.getReplicationAPI()
.createReplicationSlot()
.logical()
.withSlotName("logical_replication_slot")
.withOutputPlugin("test_decoding")
.make();
```

but when i run it I get this exception saying that I have an encoding problem.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe9 0x71 0x75
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2412)[423:org.postgresql.jdbc41:42.0.0.jre7]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2125)[423:org.postgresql.jdbc41:42.0.0.jre7]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:297)[423:org.postgresql.jdbc41:42.0.0.jre7]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428)[423:org.postgresql.jdbc41:42.0.0.jre7]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354)[423:org.postgresql.jdbc41:42.0.0.jre7]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:301)[423:org.postgresql.jdbc41:42.0.0.jre7]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:287)[423:org.postgresql.jdbc41:42.0.0.jre7]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:264)[423:org.postgresql.jdbc41:42.0.0.jre7]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:260)[423:org.postgresql.jdbc41:42.0.0.jre7]
        at org.postgresql.replication.fluent.logical.LogicalCreateSlotBuilder.make(LogicalCreateSlotBuilder.java:48)[423:org.postgresql.jdbc41:42.0.0.jre7]
        at com.soprahr.hub.replication.postgresql.activator.Activator.start(Activator.java:41)[424:com.soprahr.hub.replication.postgresql:0.0.1.SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:697)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.6.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2226)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.6.1.jar:]
        ... 16 more
```

This is my postgres config i have tried sql_ascii, utf8 for client encoding but always the same error :

```
client_encoding = windows-1251      # actually, defaults to database
                    # encoding

# These settings are initialized by initdb, but they can be changed.
lc_messages = 'French_France.1252'          # locale for system error message
                    # strings
lc_monetary = 'French_France.1252'          # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'French_France.1252'           # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'French_France.1252'              # locale for time formatting
```

Comment: Maybe you should set client_encoding to cp1252, or iso8859-1 or iso8859-15 ? (you can also set it at the start of the session via `set client_encoding iso8859-15;`

Comment: i can't set it it shows the following error Not connected to the server or the connection to the server has been closed. but when i `try show client_encoding` it gives UNICODE i tried to edit it from the config file but always UNICODE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the settings into postgres.conf

```
lc_messages = 'English_United States.1252' 
lc_monetary = 'English_United States.1252'  
lc_numeric = 'English_United States.1252'   
lc_time = 'English_United States.1252'      
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
```

And don't forget to comment "client_encoding = windows-1251".

This should work!