# Letters in error message in PostgreSQL appear wrong

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I found this thread - [PSQL : ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43586895/psql-error-invalid-byte-sequence-for-encoding-utf8), but it didn't help me, i still have this letters in error.

This is my postgres config:

```
# These settings are initialized by initdb, but they can be changed.
lc_messages = 'English_United States.1252' 
lc_monetary = 'English_United States.1252'  
lc_numeric = 'English_United States.1252'   
lc_time = 'English_United States.1252'      
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'

# - Other Defaults -
```

Error shows up after i restore database like this:
[image]

Error:
[image]

Comment: *Where* does this message appear?

Comment: What does `show  lc_ctype` return?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver it returns `Russian_Russia.1251`

Comment: @Bergi it appears after i'm trying to restore database

Comment: @Kuji Which tool are you using for that? If a cli, in which terminal?

Comment: Did you write the configs in a text file? Check the file encoding, eg using notepad++

Comment: @Bergi i'm simply press right click on database and choose Restore

Comment: @Kuji Again, in which tool?

Comment: @Bergi i added picture in the begining

Comment: @Roland It's UTF-8

Comment: Did you check the BOM, byte order mark? Try with and without it